# using header in php to jump in a different directory

Tags: php, header

My question is whether there is a way that if I want to go from index.php to another folder and run index.php again there without specifying the file name. Either way, it should run the index page when I navigate to the folder, but I haven't found an option to implement this yet.

Are there ways to do this or is it not possible?

This is how I would imagine the code:

```
<?php

// folder_name is the folder, where the index.php file is
header("Location:folder_name");

?>
```

I tried the absolute and the relative Path, but both won't work.

It changes the link, but numbers are added to the link or the link becomes infinitely long.

Comment: `Location` doesn't technically specify any file or folder, it specifies a *URL*.  The browser would then navigate to that URL.  Whatever the server returns for that URL is what the browser would receive.  If you need your web server to serve `index.php` by default for any given "folder" URL, that's something you'd configure on the web server and has nothing to do with the code shown.

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. I didn't think that this could also be due to the server itself.

Comment: So if you have an index.php inside a folder named /example which is one level down from the web root, then specifying `Location: /example` should cause the browser to redirect to the right place

Comment: You could read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's. That way all requests will go through your front controller (usually index.php). This is how most modern/semi-modern sites/frameworks work as well.

Comment: I solved the problem with a "/" at the and of the path, so the server identifies it as a folder.